# Unit tests fast in Visual Studio (2015) Test Explorer and slow in vstest.console.exe

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, nunit, vstest

I have approximately 1250 NUnit tests (actually database integration tests) which when run with the solution open in the Test Explorer in VS2015 take approximately 5mins 30secs. However, when run using the `vstest.console.exe` on the command line (correctly pointing at the same adapter in packages and with `/logger:trx`) they take approximately 45mins. Neither are run in parallel. And neither use any additional testsettings/runsettings files. The only difference I can possibly see is that in VS2015 there is an option: Keep Test Execution Engine Running

[image]

Is is possible to set the execution engine to keep running on the command line?

Comment: My current thinking is that because it doesn't keep the test execution engine running then it has to make a new db connection for each test thus slowing the run down dramatically.

Comment: I unchecked this option and ran the tests through Test Explorer again. This time the time taken is approximately the same as vstest.console.exe on the command line.

Comment: Very interesting. Where in your code do you set up the connection? Is it done for each test?

Comment: I was originally looking at this purely from a execution point of view and not looking at the individual tests. However, it appears we have an abstract test base class method that opens the SqlConnection under a [OneTimeSetup] method which is then closed in the [OneTimeTearDown] method. So the db connection theory might be a red herring.

Comment: The db connection theory wasn't off by much. It does seem that because the connection wasn't being disposed of (by virtue of the fact the execution engine not being closed), then it was able to reuse it. Have changed the tests to use a SetUpFixture class and that resolved part of the problem. The rest of the problem is to do with the order of tests being different and there appears to be tests somewhere that do not clean up after themselves and are heavily impacting others depending on when they run.